# How do I make some values of child node '.read': true, while other values '.read': false?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have a database having a node called 'details', which has some numeric valued child nodes. Each child node store details like Name, Age, Gender, etc. I need to make the Name to be visible to all and Age, Gender not visible. Please help me with the Firebase Rule and JavaScript code.

I have already did a Rule as given below

```
{
    "rules": {
        "register" : {
            "details": {
                ".read": false,
                ".write": true,
                "$userid": {
                    "name": {
                        ".read": true
                    },
                    "age": {
                        ".read": false
                    },
                    "gender": {
                        ".read": false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My database looks like this

```
mainblock
    register
        details
            1
                name: "ALPHA"
                age: "10"
                gender: "Male"
            18
                name: "BETA"
                age: "15"
                gender: "Female"
            19
                name: "GAMMA"
                age: "18"
                gender: "Male"
```

And the JavaScript code used is

```
var query = firebase.database().ref("register/details/").orderByKey();
query.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var nm = childSnapshot.child("name").val();
        console.log(nm)
    });
});
```

But I have got an error saying

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: permission_denied at /register/details: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.
    at H (firebase-storage.js:3476)
    at onComplete (firebase-storage.js:3476)
    at Object.onComplete (firebase-storage.js:3476)
    at firebase-storage.js:3476
    at e.vr (firebase-storage.js:3476)
    at t.vr (firebase-storage.js:3476)
    at t.cr (firebase-storage.js:3476)
    at e.onMessage (firebase-storage.js:3476)
    at e.nt (firebase-storage.js:3476)
    at e.handleIncomingFrame (firebase-storage.js:3476)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the first read statement. Only the first `".read"` rule is accounted when trying to access the database because ["cascade in such a way that granting a read or write privilege to a parent node always grants that read/write access to all child nodes"](https://howtofirebase.com/firebase-security-rules-88d94606ce4a). Same is for `".write"`, only `".validate"` does not cascade and therefore all validation rules in the tree must apply to allow a write.
More on that [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/).

```
{
    "rules": {
        "register" : {
            "details": {
                ".write": true,
                "$userid": {
                    "name": {
                        ".read": true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The other `".read": false` statements are unnecessary because the permissions are false by default/when not set.